# How to save half-made service in Automator?

Tags: automator

How to save half-made service in Automator without making it active, as it is not finished?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if it's unfinished. Doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will save it under `~/Library/Services`.

Taking the Service out of `~/Library/Services` and restarting Finder (if you want immediate effect) will make this Service not to be shown under **Menu / Services**. Putting it back will, of course, make it appear again.

It does not matter where the file is placed, you'll be able to open it with **Automator** to continue editing it.

Comment: It'll be accessible in menu/Services although it doesn't work, which is what I want to avoid at the moment.

Comment: Taking the Service out of `~/Library/Services` and restarting Finder will do the trick. Putting it back will, of course, make it appear again under **Menu / Services**.

Comment: You mean- if the Service file is saved somewhere else it won't appear in **Menu**, but it can be open with Automator, right? Could you this time edit your answer directly?